# check return value fread and fwrite

Tags: c, return-value, fwrite, fread

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  if(argc != 3){
    printf("Usage: ./copy filename newfile\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  int bytes;
  long file_size, file_copied_size;
  FILE *file_to_copy, *new_file;

  if((file_to_copy = fopen(argv[1], "rb")) == NULL){
    printf("File cannot be opened - read\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  if((new_file = fopen(argv[2], "wb")) == NULL){
    printf("File cannot be opened - write\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  fseek(file_to_copy, 0, SEEK_END);
  file_size = ftell(file_to_copy);
  rewind(file_to_copy);

  char *buffer = malloc(1024 * 1024); /* Imposto un buffer di 1MB per maggiore efficienza */ 
  if(!buffer){
    printf("Errore allocazione memoria\n");
    fclose(file_to_copy);
    fclose(new_file);
    exit(1);
  }

   /* In questo modo copio file grandi 1MB alla volta così il trasferimento è più veloce ed efficiente inoltre fread() ritorna 0 quando c'è un errore o quando incontra EOF */
  //while ((bytes=fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), file_to_copy)) > 0){
  while (!feof(file_to_copy)){
    bytes = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), file_to_copy);
    fwrite(buffer, 1, bytes, new_file);
    if(ferror(new_file)){
      perror("Errore scrittura"); /* perror printa anche l'errore che ferror ha incontrato */
      fclose(file_to_copy);
      fclose(new_file);
      exit(1);
    }
  }

  fseek(new_file, 0, SEEK_END);
  file_copied_size = ftell(new_file);
  rewind(new_file);
  if(file_size != file_copied_size){
    printf("Il file %s non è stato copiato correttamente\n", argv[2]);
  }
  else{
    printf("File successfully copied :)\n");
  }  
  fclose(file_to_copy);
  fclose(new_file);
  free(buffer);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**EDIT: i've updated the code**
I have some doubts:
1) I have to check the return code of fread because - for example - if bytes become 0 due to an error, 0 will be written into the copied file.
But my question is: how to do it?  Because fread *can* return 0 but can also return *a short value* ....
2) how can read go throught the file? If i copy a 5MB file how can fread move from 1MB in 1MB without something that say to it "hey you have to put your offset 1MB after the 1MB you've just copied"?
3) why not to clear the buffer after every use? I mean something like:

```
while (!feof(file_to_copy)){
        bytes = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), file_to_copy);
        fwrite(buffer, 1, bytes, new_file);
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
}
```

Comment: try storing in `size_t` instead of an int

Comment: @polslinux, I usually use fread(buffer, file_size, 1, file_to_copy), and check the return of fread whether is equal to 1

Answer (score 5):

Usually, you *don't* want to try to copy an entire file in a single read/write cycle. This has (among other things) a fairly substantial chance of your memory allocation failing, or being horribly inefficient if you end up allocating/using some virtual memory.

Instead, you usually want to allocate a buffer of reasonable size (say, a megabyte or two) then do the copying in a loop, something like:

```
char *buffer = malloc(1024 * 1024);  

while ((bytes=fread(buffer, 1, 1024 * 1024, infile)) > 0)
    fwrite(buffer, 1, bytes, outfile);
```

You can, of course, also check the return value from `fwrite` and (for example) exit the loop if it doesn't write the amount you requested. This is particularly important if, for example, you're moving a file instead of just copying it -- you only want to remove the original when/if you're certain the copy has succeeded.

Comment: but how can i check the return value of fwrite? I got a stack overflow :(

Comment: but why do you check bytes > 0 ? Does fread return 0 when it reach the EOF? And also why you don't "clear" the buffer before reusing it?

Comment: @polslinux: `fread` returns the number of items it read successfully, so we write that number back out. Yes, when it can't read anything it returns 0 (regardless of whether that's from end of file or something else like a disk error). You don't need to clear the buffer, because the only part we use is the part that `fread` had just written to.

Comment: Ah ok i've understand...but what i don't unserstand is: if we allocate 1MB for the buffer and we write 1MB into the buffer, next time we write into it - for example - 400KB there are other 600KB that have been written and are dirty...or the malloced buffer doesn't work like array??

Comment: @polslinux: Look carefully -- we keep the return value from `fread` in `bytes`. When we call `fwrite`, we pass `bytes` (i.e., the amount that was read) as to amount to write. So, if we read a whole buffer full, that's what we write -- but if we only read a partial buffer, that's how much we write.

Comment: ok..i've understand now :D many thanks :D last thing i haven't undestand is:  how can fread iterate the file? If i copy a 5MB file how can fread move from 1MB in 1MB without something that say to it "hey you have to put your offset 1MB after the 1MB you've just copied"?

Comment: @polslinux: Every file (that you open in C) has a "current position" pointer. When you read, that's where you read from. When you write, that's where you write to. Anytime you read or write, it's updated to the new position (i.e., following what you just read/wrote).

Comment: @JerryCoffin I think your sizeof(buffer) will not work as expected. This won't return 1024*1024, but the size of the pointer (8 bytes on 64 bit archs).

Comment: @Arne `sizeof(buffer)` will yield the size of a pointer, but that's what you should expect when you apply `sizeof` to a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

According to your posted code, I think you have made a mistake at this line.

```
fwrite(buffer, 1, file_size, file_to_copy);
```

you try to write something into the file_to_copy which is already closed, that is not allowed by program, so it gives you a stackoverflow.

Comment: O.o i'm an idiot xD the smallest error is always the most difficult to find :D

Answer (score 1):

You call [ferror()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/ferror/) to check the error status of an I/O stream if the fread/fwrite doesn't copy the number of chars you expect

Comment: oh thanks! This can be good :) EDIT: is this right? `while ((bytes=fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), file_to_copy)) > 0){
    fwrite(buffer, 1, bytes, new_file);
    if(ferror(new_file){
      printf("Errore scrittura\n");
      fclose(file_to_copy);
      fclose(new_file);
      exit(1);
    }
  }`

Comment: @polslinux - yes, see also perror() it prints the actual system error message that ferror() found