# correct use of error checking (incl. ferror) when using fread and fwrite

Tags: c

I am writing a C program that does this:
- reads from a file in blocks (into an array)
- perform modifications on the data in the array
- then write the array data into a newly created file

The file-processing loop code goes like this:

```
//(buffer_array is a dynamically allocated char array and quite big)

while (0 < (bytes_read = fread(buffer_array, 1, sizeof(buffer_array), source_file))) {

    modification_function(buffer_array, .....);

    bytes_written = fwrite(buffer, 1, bytes_read, target_file); 

    //Checking for errors - is this the right way of doing error checking? 
    if(bytes_written != bytes_read || ferror(target_file) || ferror(source_file)) {
        /* Handle file errors */
    }
}
```

Is the if-condition for error checking overkill?

Is it enough to use ferror like this? if(bytes_written != bytes_read) {/*call ferror here to figure out what went wrong*/}?

What is the best way to use ferror and other error-checking mechanisms in this kind of scenario?

Thanks! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [check return value fread and fwrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11054750/check-return-value-fread-and-fwrite)

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to use ferror as you state at the bottom of your question:

```
if (bytes_written != bytes_read) {
    // determine what to do based on ferror()
}
```

That's correct and concise.